# Is there a way to include some text into monit's alert message?

Tags: monit, alerts

I plan to use program check, with it's exit code I can force monit to send alert mail message, ok. But how to include into that message some output produced by checking program?

I could modify program to write it's output in some file but how to tell monit to use this file during message composing?

There is something `description` field in mail-format, is it suitable for this purpose?

From [monit's docs](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#Message-format):

> The subject and body may contain $NAME variables, which are expanded by Monit. Here is a list of variables that can be used when composing an alert message
>
> …
>
> $DESCRIPTION The description of the error condition

Comment: did you check here https://serverfault.com/questions/901760/monit-use-content-match-on-check-file-if-match-xxx ?